How can I take pictures of my back?
I have a substantial number of moles on my back and my doctor has advised me to take pictures of it regularly so that I (or she) can watch for moles that need to be removed. I have two cameras, a Canon T1i and the one in my phone, a Google Pixel 7, but I have no idea how to take a picture of my own back since I can't figure out how to frame or focus it.
Is there some way to get the pictures without having to get someone else involved, preferably without having to buy expensive gear?

What have you tried so far?

You can fix your camera on a tripod and place a chair/stool about 5 - 7 feet from the tripod. Let the chair be against a wall. Focus the camera on your chair/on the wall where your back might be positioned. Try with an aperture setting of about f/5.6. Use the Self Timer on the camera, set it to 10 seconds and click and go sit on the chair/stool with your back to the camera. When you hear the click after 10 seconds, check your picture. Try a few snaps. You can make any adjustments like distance, lighting, aperture and seating position until you get the picture you are satisfied with.
I tried something similar with my Nikon ZF C digital camera and it is easy.
In case you dont have a tripod, the camera can be set on a desk or something similar. I noted Canon T1i has a self timer.

You can also use your camera's built-in flash for lighting.

I looked up on Google search for "sit on chair backwards", and you can try one of those too.

It is also a good idea to have something with a known size on your back near to the moles as a reference - for a little money you can get an L shaped  reference but a couple of plastic rulers stuck together at right angles will do. Ideally on your back but at the same distance & in frame will do. This allows for growth to be checked.

A belated thank you @prasad. This offers perhaps the best approach next to getting someone else to take the pictures ;-)

@SteveBarnes - Getting an L-shaped reference makes a lot of sense. Would I find that at the camera store?

@Henry - you may get one from a camera store if they stock forensic supplies or even from a sewing shop (as a Quilting Ruler).

Your Pixel 7 is auto-focus and seems to work with the actual image rather than using some sort of rangefinding (that would focus on the mirror).  The easiest way, then, is to use the front camera, stand with your back to a suitable mirror, aim the camera over your shoulder and compose on the screen, and shoot.
The default setting will mirror image the front camera, which will undo the reversal from the actual mirror, and you'll find even the somewhat reduced resolution of the front camera more than adequate for tracking moles.  Auto-everything (and a little AI thrown in to do the best possible job) means you don't have to worry about exposure etc., and the resulting images are easily transferred via email app or SMS.

@ZeissIcon - I haven't been able to figure out a way to set a mirror so that I could get the shots I need.

A common full length mirror such as many people use to evaluate their state of dress should be adequate.  For the back above the waist, a bathroom mirror might well do the job.  Your position would be close to the classic selfie pose, but with the phone screen pointed at the mirror instead of at your face.

You might be able to control your Canon T1i via a wired ("tethered") connection, using an app like DSLR Controller:

DSLR Controller was the first and is still the best app to fully control your Canon EOS DSLR from your Android device, with nothing more than a USB cable. No computer or laptop required, no root required. All you need is a compatible mobile device, a compatible camera, and the right USB cable.

(I am not an Android user; I can't comment on how well it works, or if the app even still works. YMMV)

Thanks for the suggestion. I just searched on DSLR Controller in the Google Play Store and several apps came up but none of them were called specifically DSLR Controller; Google seemed to treat my search as a generic term, like "board game", rather than a specific title. Maybe the actual program by that name is gone now. In any case, the big challenge is framing the shot when I can't see what I'm doing. I'm not sure if these apps do that.

If you follow the link in my answer, it takes you to this Google play store page. The point of the app is to allow you to connect your phone (via USB) to your DSLR, so you can set up your camera, and use your phone (and phone's screen) to control your DSLR, see the framing, etc. This has always been possible if connecting your DSLR to a laptop via USB. If you have a laptop, you can see what your camera sees via USB. This app allows your Google phone to control your DSLR camera instead.
